# Corrupted network write in kj AsyncIoStream

Tags: linux, c++11, asyncsocket, capnproto, kj

I'm implementing an networked application on the excellent [kj-async library](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html#kj-library) from Cap'n Proto.

The example code below serves a (large, preloaded) file (`argv[1]`) over TCP. If I redirect it directly to a file with `nc localhost 9004 > test`, the file is retrieved correctly.

If I let the file output to the terminal without redirecting to a file, I see intermittent corruption. I suspect the underlying call to `::write` is failing with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` when the terminal can't write the output fast enough, and the next call is somehow using incorrect offsets. This was much more reliably reproducible when I tried fetching it over wifi.

I think I must have some issues with object lifetimes, but there is no hint from valgrind.

I used [angular.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js) but any not-too-small file reproduced the problem for me

I'm on 64bit Linux 4.1.6 (Arch) with [libkj from git](https://github.com/sandstorm-io/capnproto)

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <kj/async-io.h>

class Server : public kj::TaskSet::ErrorHandler {
public:
    Server(const char* filename) :
        tasks(*this),
        ctx(kj::setupAsyncIo())
    {
        std::ifstream fstr(filename);
        fstr.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        size_t sz = fstr.tellg();
        if(fstr.rdstate() == 0) {
            large.resize(sz);
            fstr.seekg(0);
            fstr.read(&large[0], sz);
        }
    }
    void taskFailed(kj::Exception&& exception) override {}
    void run() {
        tasks.add(ctx.provider->getNetwork().parseAddress("*:9004", 0)
               .then([&](kj::Own<kj::NetworkAddress>&& addr) {
            auto listener = addr->listen();
            accept(kj::mv(listener));
        }));
        kj::NEVER_DONE.wait(ctx.waitScope);
    }
private:
    void accept(kj::Own<kj::ConnectionReceiver>&& listener) {
        auto ptr = listener.get();
        tasks.add(ptr->accept().then(kj::mvCapture(kj::mv(listener),
           [&](kj::Own<kj::ConnectionReceiver>&& listener,
                kj::Own<kj::AsyncIoStream>&& cn) {
            accept(kj::mv(listener));
            tasks.add(cn->write(large.c_str(), large.size()).attach(kj::mv(cn)));
        })));
    }

private:    
    kj::TaskSet tasks;
    kj::AsyncIoContext ctx;
    std::string large;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Server s(argv[1]);
    s.run();
}
```

Compiled and run:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lkj-async -lkj -o test
./test path/to/angular.min.js
```

Request:

```
nc localhost 9004
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete test case! Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce -- transferring a 15MB file over my LAN seems to produce exactly the correct bytes. Could you perhaps post copies of your file before and after corruption? The corruption pattern may provide some hints.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but note that I'd recommend only using `[&]` for lambdas that are expected to be called synchronously (before the surrounding stack frame ends). Otherwise any references captured could be dangling by the time the callback is called. In both cases in your code, `[this]` is sufficient as a capture list.

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I can't reproduce this today either. Perhaps it was just a glitch in the terminal emulator - as now it looks like the wifi issue was unrelated. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No problem, nice to have confirmation that people are successfully using these interfaces. :)